# jquery datepicker and time dynamically disable

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a calendar and a time

i used jquery date picker for the calendar 
and a simple select box for the time

how can i disable both date and time dynamically?
for the time when the time is already booked in a date
it will be remove in the select box for that specific date only

and for the date when all the time is fully booked for the date
the specific date will be disabled.

i will be using php and mysql for storing data
also is having a database for example
db_calendar
(table)dates
    (column)date
    (column)time

is it enough to create the functionality i want?

disable i mean is like this

```
    var unavailableDates = [
    "29-8-2013", 
    "14-8-2013", 
    "15-8-2013"
    ];

    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate: +0,
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "MM d",
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'disable'?

Comment: What is the question you are asking? Given the code you provided, does it meet your requirements?

Comment: how can i disable both date and time dynamically? for the time when the time is already booked in a date it will be remove in the select box for that specific date only

and for the date when all the time is fully booked for the date the specific date will be disabled.

i will be using php and mysql for storing data also is having a database for example db_calendar (table)dates (column)date (column)time
is it enough to create the functionality i want?

this is my question and the code i provided is for the calendar only..that code i posted is works to disable date's in calendar but not dynamic

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are having trouble with? Are you getting the unavailable dates from the database okay? Is the code you posted working as intended?

Comment: my problem is this value
    var unavailableDates = [
    "29-8-2013", 
    "14-8-2013", 
    "15-8-2013"
    ];                                                               
is static i manually put it
i want to do it dynamically which is the value of unavailableDates will come from mysql that's first , second is there will be an array of time inside of the date's value in unavailableDates for example
this date 29-8-2013 has ["8:30","9:30","11:30"]